# Hide everything else, but

Tags: jquery

***Here's the code:*** http://jsfiddle.net/t2nite/KCY8g/

What I'm trying to get the **`SHOW`** buttons below the **`HIDE/SHOW ALL`** button is if you press one button it will show it's text and hide the other texts.

I used this code, but as soon as I hit show on any button, it will show and hide itself.

```
$(".show").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().find("p").show(200);
   $("p").not(this).hide(200);
});​
```

Help.

Comment: `this` does not refer to a `p` element, so `$("p").not(this)` is equivalent to `$('p')` and will select all `p` elements on the page. What you want is to get a reference to the `p` elements corresponding to the button first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem was that `this` in the show function was not a `<p>` it was the button.

```
$(".show").click(function() {
    var $thisP = $(this).parent().find("p")
    $thisP.show(200);
    $("p").not($thisP).hide(200);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KCY8g/11/

Answer (score 2):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DNpKN/)

Basically you want to hide all the 'itsawrap p' areas besides the current one.

```
$(".show").click(function() {
    var _p = $(this).parent().find('p');
    // maybe even do: $(this).closest('.itsawrap').find('p');
    // (if you ever think you'll wrap any of these things in other divs/etc

    _p.show(200);
    $('.itsawrap p').not(_p).hide();
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the show code to be this:

```
$(".show").click(function() {
    var container = $(this).closest(".itsawrap");
    $(".itsawrap").not(container).find("p").hide(200);
    container.find("p").show(200);
});​
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6ypRz/

This works at the container level so you can operate on the desired containers.

Comment: Tricky and it works, but it only hides the problem.

$("p").not(this).hide(200); <--- "this" is not your "p", it's the "button".  The .not is useless.

Comment: @MaximeMorin - I've updated my answer with a more complete solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't think order mattered in scripting.

Comment: @t2nite - order doesn't matter if the two statements aren't operating on the same objects, but if they are touching the same objects, then order does matter.  My current answer separates out the two classes of objects so the last two lines of code are not order dependent, though it's generally safer to do `.hide()` operations first and then `.show()` as this is more likely to end up with the desired result if there is overlap.  Also, note that `.closest()` is a little more flexible than `.parent()` as it won't break if someone tweaks the HTML with another level of container.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    var oneshow = false;
    $(".para2, .para3, .para4").each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
            oneshow = true;
        }
    });
    if (oneshow == true) {
        $(".para2, .para3, .para4").hide(200);
    } else {
        $(".para2, .para3, .para4").show(200);
    }
});

$(".hide").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find("p").hide(200);
});

$(".show").click(function() {
    var p = $(this).parent().find("p");
    $(p).show(200);
    $(parent).not(p).hide(200);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in `this`.

```
$(".show").click(function() {
    var p = $(this).parent().find("p");
    p.show(200);
    $("p").not(p).hide(200);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the most short ways:

```
$(".show").click(function(e) {
    $("p").not($(this).parent().find("p").show(200)).hide(200);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/librasoft/KCY8g/16/)

Answer (score 0):

the mistake is the the parent "this" is the button, so $("p").not(this).hide(200); says all p's except your button, which is still all the p's.

```
$(".show").click(function() {
     var parent = $(this).parent();
     $(".itsawrap").not(parent).find('p').hide(200);
     parent.find('p').show(200);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/renekoch/KCY8g/17/